# Maven project build problems

Tags: maven-2

I have a maven 2 web project which I have checked out of svn.

My settings file has a mirror configured.

When  I do a clean install maven is trying to download jars from the mirror and since it is unable to find the jars it says the build fails.

But when i check my local repo I see all the required jars.

So is it possible to change my local repo as the mirror location ?

Is this a right approach ?

---

Editing the question to post my error

First I get a set of warnings

```
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.2
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-ui:jar:3.3.3.Final
 [WARNING] Missing POM for cglib:cglib:jar:2.2
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl:jar:3.3.3.Final
 [WARNING] Missing POM for opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.3
 [WARNING] Missing POM for commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.3.Final
 [WARNING] Missing POM for com.sun.facelets:jsf-facelets:jar:1.1.14.P1
 [WARNING] Missing POM for javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_12
 [WARNING] Missing POM for javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_12
 [WARNING] Missing POM for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4
 [WARNING] Missing POM for javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jboss.el:jboss-el:jar:2.0.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam:jar:2.0.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-debug:jar:2.0.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ui:jar:2.0.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ioc:jar:2.0.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5
 [WARNING] Missing POM for commons-math:commons-math:jar:1.2
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.6
 [WARNING] Missing POM for javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0
 [WARNING] Missing POM for hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.4.SP1
 [WARNING] Missing POM for hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for hibernate-entitymanager:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.1.GA
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.0.0.ga
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:2.4.0
 [WARNING] Missing POM for commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3
 [WARNING] Missing POM for commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.3
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6
 [WARNING] Missing POM for opensymphony:quartz:jar:1.6.3
 [WARNING] Missing POM for opensymphony:quartz-oracle:jar:1.6.3
 [WARNING] Missing POM for jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12
 [WARNING] Missing POM for com.itextpdf:itextpdf:jar:5.0.5
 [WARNING] Missing POM for org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.9
 [WARNING] Missing POM for com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1
 [WARNING] Missing POM for ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3
```

Then I get the following set of errors

```
         1) nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:0.9.5

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=nekohtml -DartifactId=nekohtml -Dversion=0.9.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=nekohtml -DartifactId=nekohtml -Dversion=0.9.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:0.9.5

    2) ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=ehcache -DartifactId=ehcache -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=ehcache -DartifactId=ehcache -Dversion=1.2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3

    3) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ioc:jar:2.0.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-ioc -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-ioc -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ioc:jar:2.0.1.GA

    4) commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-validator -DartifactId=commons-validator -Dversion=1.1.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-validator -DartifactId=commons-validator -Dversion=1.1.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.3

    5) org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:2.4.0

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.lucene -DartifactId=lucene-core -Dversion=2.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.lucene -DartifactId=lucene-core -Dversion=2.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:2.4.0

    6) org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-ui:jar:3.3.3.Final

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.ui -DartifactId=richfaces-ui -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.ui -DartifactId=richfaces-ui -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-ui:jar:3.3.3.Final

    7) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.3.Final

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.framework -DartifactId=richfaces-api -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.framework -DartifactId=richfaces-api -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.3.Final

    8) commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-digester -DartifactId=commons-digester -Dversion=1.8 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-digester -DartifactId=commons-digester -Dversion=1.8 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8

    9) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl:jar:3.3.3.Final

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.framework -DartifactId=richfaces-impl -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.richfaces.framework -DartifactId=richfaces-impl -Dversion=3.3.3.Final -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-impl:jar:3.3.3.Final

    10) commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-lang -DartifactId=commons-lang -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-lang -DartifactId=commons-lang -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3

    11) com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.thoughtworks.xstream -DartifactId=xstream -Dversion=1.3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.thoughtworks.xstream -DartifactId=xstream -Dversion=1.3.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1

    12) org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring -Dversion=2.5 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5

    13) org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.slf4j -DartifactId=slf4j-api -Dversion=1.5.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.slf4j -DartifactId=slf4j-api -Dversion=1.5.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6

    14) org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.slf4j -DartifactId=slf4j-log4j12 -Dversion=1.5.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.slf4j -DartifactId=slf4j-log4j12 -Dversion=1.5.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.6

    15) cglib:cglib:jar:2.2

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=cglib -DartifactId=cglib -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=cglib -DartifactId=cglib -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) cglib:cglib:jar:2.2

    16) opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=oscache -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=oscache -Dversion=2.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) opensymphony:oscache:jar:2.3

    17) com.sun.facelets:jsf-facelets:jar:1.1.14.P1

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.sun.facelets -DartifactId=jsf-facelets -Dversion=1.1.14.P1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sun.facelets -DartifactId=jsf-facelets -Dversion=1.1.14.P1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) com.sun.facelets:jsf-facelets:jar:1.1.14.P1

    18) javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_12

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.faces -DartifactId=jsf-api -Dversion=1.2_12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.faces -DartifactId=jsf-api -Dversion=1.2_12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) javax.faces:jsf-api:jar:1.2_12

    19) javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_12

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.faces -DartifactId=jsf-impl -Dversion=1.2_12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.faces -DartifactId=jsf-impl -Dversion=1.2_12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) javax.faces:jsf-impl:jar:1.2_12

    20) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet -DartifactId=servlet-api -Dversion=2.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4

    21) javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet.jsp -DartifactId=jsp-api -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.servlet.jsp -DartifactId=jsp-api -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1

    22) org.jboss.el:jboss-el:jar:2.0.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.el -DartifactId=jboss-el -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.el -DartifactId=jboss-el -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.el:jboss-el:jar:2.0.1.GA

    23) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam:jar:2.0.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam:jar:2.0.1.GA

    24) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-debug:jar:2.0.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-debug -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-debug -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-debug:jar:2.0.1.GA

    25) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ui:jar:2.0.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-ui -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jboss.seam -DartifactId=jboss-seam-ui -Dversion=2.0.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.jboss.seam:jboss-seam-ui:jar:2.0.1.GA

    26) commons-math:commons-math:jar:1.2

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=commons-math -DartifactId=commons-math -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=commons-math -DartifactId=commons-math -Dversion=1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) commons-math:commons-math:jar:1.2

    27) org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.6

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring-mock -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=spring-mock -Dversion=2.0.6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.springframework:spring-mock:jar:2.0.6

    28) javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.persistence -DartifactId=persistence-api -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.persistence -DartifactId=persistence-api -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0

    29) hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.4.SP1

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate3 -Dversion=3.2.4.SP1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate3 -Dversion=3.2.4.SP1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) hibernate:hibernate3:jar:3.2.4.SP1

    30) hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=hibernate-annotations -DartifactId=hibernate-annotations -Dversion=3.3.0.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=hibernate-annotations -DartifactId=hibernate-annotations -Dversion=3.3.0.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) hibernate-annotations:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.3.0.GA

    31) hibernate-entitymanager:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.1.GA

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=hibernate-entitymanager -DartifactId=hibernate-entitymanager -Dversion=3.3.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=hibernate-entitymanager -DartifactId=hibernate-entitymanager -Dversion=3.3.1.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) hibernate-entitymanager:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.1.GA

    32) org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.0.0.ga

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate-validator -Dversion=3.0.0.ga -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate-validator -Dversion=3.0.0.ga -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:3.0.0.ga

    33) opensymphony:quartz:jar:1.6.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=quartz -Dversion=1.6.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=quartz -Dversion=1.6.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) opensymphony:quartz:jar:1.6.3

    34) org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.9

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springmodules -DartifactId=spring-modules-cache -Dversion=0.9 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.springmodules -DartifactId=spring-modules-cache -Dversion=0.9 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) org.springmodules:spring-modules-cache:jar:0.9

    35) jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=jfree -DartifactId=jfreechart -Dversion=1.0.12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=jfree -DartifactId=jfreechart -Dversion=1.0.12 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12

    36) opensymphony:quartz-oracle:jar:1.6.3

      Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

      Then, install it using the command: 
          mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=quartz-oracle -Dversion=1.6.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

      Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
          mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=opensymphony -DartifactId=quartz-oracle -Dversion=1.6.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

      Path to dependency: 
        1) myproject:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        2) opensymphony:quartz-oracle:jar:1.6.3
```

All these dependencies with the same version are already there  in my local repository.
I also tried using the tips given but of no avail

Comment: Make sure that all of your dependencies have a version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the offline flag in Maven `-o` so that only your local repo will be used. If build then still complains about a missing dependency, the problem is somewhere else (maybe your local repo contains another version, or something like this).

Comment: okay i get it. My error log throws a lot of warnings regarding the missing poms for the dependencies that are already there in my local repo. So how do I generate the poms for these ?

Comment: if these dependencies are in remote repo, simply delete then in local repo and rerun mvn. Other wise use maven deploy plugin (see  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) with option `-DgeneratePom=true` to reinstall them in you local repo with a new pom

Comment: Hey even after doing an offline build I get this error Failed to execute goal org.richfaces.cdk:maven-resource-dependency-plugin:3.3.3.Final:assembly-resources (default)

Comment: @Anand. Please edit the question and post the stacktrace you get when you run maven with -e.

Answer (score 1):

Maven does look at the local repository first, before it queries the mirror/remote repository. It looks like your local repository has the jars, but not the pom files. Could these have copied/placed manually?  As it is, it is not useful to maven.

There are two ways to solve the issue.

- Allow maven to download the dependencies by connecting to the internet (if the mirror does not hold the jars).  This is what happens by default.  If you are behind a proxy, you can configure a `<proxy>` setting so that maven connect to central repo through the proxy.
- Manually install each dependant jars using the `maven install:install-file` command in the local repository.  This will automatically create the poms for the jars and thus make it available to maven in subsequent runs.

Comment: I have configured a proxy and I have also tried the maven install:install-file command. When I try the install command it says a build failure as the jar is already there in the repository.

Comment: @Anand. Try removing the folders holding the relevant dependencies and retry.

Comment: @Raghuram removing the specific jars and rechecking the maven dependencies worked for me causing problems worked for me.